# Rails Complex Active Record Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys, relationship, table-relationships

I have a complex active record relationship in mind, and was wondering how exactly I would accomplish it. In essence:

A **User** can create a **Board**. A user can then add other users to that board for collaborative editing. Added users form a **Team**. Each added User has a **Role** in each board, (Admin, Editor, Viewer).

I was thinking of setting it up this way:

- A **User** has many **Boards**
- A **Board** has many **Users** through **Teams**
- A **Team** has many **Users**?

The role part has been confusing me. Do I have to set up a **TeamUser** model which has many **Roles**, or does each **User** have many **Roles** which belong to a **Board**? Does a Role even have to be it's own model?

What is the most effective way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user could belong to many teams and could have many roles, logic could be something like:

You need a join table to supply the N-to-N relationship between User and Board model. But the thing is, when you add a user to a board, you give them a role in that participation. It's a good place to hold role info in that participation. So our UsersBoards join-table transform into the Participation model (Or whatever you like to call it). Our participation model now holds the user, board and role info (All of them is foreign-key).

I didn't exactly understand the purpose of the Team model but I think it's easy to add a user to a team when it's necessary. It will not hurt to our logic.

Also, if you don't plan to add more features in the future, role can be an enum too.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :participations
  has_many :boards, through: :participations
end

class Board < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, through: :participations
end

class Participation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :board
  enum role: [ :admin, :editor, :viewer ]
end

user = User.first
user.participations.first.board #Board
user.participations.first.admin? #true
user.boards
```

And you can add helper methods or [delegate](http://delegate) to models for shortening the query.

Comment: I was thinking of using the Team model as the join-table between users and boards. A team has many users, and a board would have one team.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could list the belongs_to and has_many relationships that I would have to setup to achieve this. From what I understand, the User model would be: `has_many :boards, through: :participation`.                                                                 The Boards model would be: `has_many :users, through: :participation`. ­                   
The Participation model would be: `belongs_to: user; belongs_to: board; has_one: role`. And the Role model would be: `belongs_to: participation`?

Comment: I just edited my answer and added a code example too. Happy hacking!